# Error Duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat$GestureDetectorCompatImpl.class, in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, duplicates, google-play-services, gesturedetector

I am using android studio 2.1.3. Here is my gradle code:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        }
    }
    apply plugin: 'android'

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
        compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

        defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minSdkVersion 9
            targetSdkVersion 20
        }

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

            instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

            debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
            release.setRoot('build-types/release')
        }
    }
```

**When running, i get the following error like this:**

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     android/support/v4/view/GestureDetectorCompat$GestureDetectorCompatImpl.class

**Please Could you tell me how to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you came from an Eclipse project.

You don't need JAR files for the support libraries.

Remove the support JAR from the `libs/` and update your Gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19+' 
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'  // Should update this

    // compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') // Remove this
```

> I am using android studio 2.1.3

I suggest you upgrade your IDE (and Gradle while you are at it)

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007, Yes that's right this project from Eclips. i have removed compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar') and update my google-play-service to 9.0.0. i still get error. I am a newbie i just want to ask, How to remove the support JAR from the libs and update Gradle file like you suggest me?